# Name of the "You are defending them, so you must be one of them" fallacy?

Tags: single-word-requests

I see this periodically when someone is arguing about a group of people, such as defending a certain group of individuals, or even just trying to explain why something is the way it is. They are accused of being "one of them", or being "with them" to try and invalidate their argument.

Is there a name for this specific type of fallacy, other than an ad-hominem?

Comment: See [Wikipedia: Association fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_fallacy#Guilt_by_association_as_an_ad_hominem_fallacy) (Guilt by association as an ad hominem fallacy).

Comment: @Mick: Care to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these types of fallacies can also be called Association Fallacies or guilt by association.

"An association fallacy is an informal inductive fallacy which asserts, by irrelevant association  that qualities of one thing are inherently qualities of another." -Wikipedia

For further reading see:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_fallacy#Guilt_by_association_as_an_ad_hominem_fallacy

https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/10/Ad-Hominem-Guilt-by-Association